# Eucalapyus comonents are not enabled during the registeration step

Tags: ubuntu, eucalyptus

I am trying to install Eucalyptus 3.3.0 on Ubuntu (cloud in a box ). I am following the steps provied [here](http://alinush.org/2013/07/21/how-to-compile-and-install-eucalyptus-3-3-0-on-ubuntu-13-04-from-github-sources-cloud-in-a-box/.)

when I try to register the components of eucalyptus, there are registered without "enabled" state. they are must be enabled.

for example : trying to resister clusters , but it got "NOTREADY" state as below:

```
sudo -u root /usr/sbin/euca_conf --register-cluster --partition $cluster --host $extaddr --component cc-$extaddr

SERVICE cluster         cluster01       cc-10.0.0.100   NOTREADY    33      http://10.0.0.100:8774/axis2/services/EucalyptusCC  arn:euca:eucalyptus:cluster01:cluster:cc-10.0.0.100/
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.100 port 22: No route to host
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
error: key sync using rsync failed: Command '['rsync', '-az', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cloud-cert.pem', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cloud-pk.pem', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cluster01/node-cert.pem', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cluster01/node-pk.pem', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cluster01/cluster-cert.pem', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cluster01/cluster-pk.pem', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cluster01/vtunpass', 'root@10.0.0.100:/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys']' returned non-zero exit status 255
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.100 port 22: No route to host
lost connection
error: key sync using scp failed: Command '['scp', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cloud-cert.pem', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cloud-pk.pem', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cluster01/node-cert.pem', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cluster01/node-pk.pem', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cluster01/cluster-cert.pem', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cluster01/cluster-pk.pem', '/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cluster01/vtunpass', 'root@10.0.0.100:/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys']' returned non-zero exit status 1
asma@asma-MacBookPro:~$
```

to check the components registeration,

```
sudo euca_conf --list-clouds --list-walrus --list-clusters  

warning: No credentials found; attempting local authentication
CLUSTER cluster01       cc-10.0.0.100   10.0.0.100                  NOTREADY    {}
warning: No credentials found; attempting local authentication
WALRUS  walrus          walrus-10.0.0.100   10.0.0.100                  BROKEN  {}
```

you can see one is BROKEN and the other is NOTREADY

how can we resolve this ?? how to make the components enabled?  plz help .

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you copied and pasted the instructions word-for-word. In step 12, you will see the following comment -

```
# WARNING: the assumption here is that you are behind a NAT'ed network (you are using a router)
# and your NAT-assigned IP address is 10.0.0.100. also, the IP address on the br0 bridge should be 10.1.0.1 
... 
extaddr=10.0.0.100 
...
```

You need to fill in the appropriate values for `extaddr` and the other variables. The error message is indicating that 10.0.0.100 is unreachable.

Comment: @Was Wannemacher thank you for your reply. I have a poor knowledge in networking . So I need a help. My network connection ( Wifi ) information is as follow : IPv4 Address : 10.0.0.6 IPv4 : 255.255.255.0 IPv4 default gateway 10.0.0.1 IPv4 DNS Server: 75.75.75.57, 75.75.76.76 So, how it would be my cloud network configuration in order to not be conflicted?